# Inverse of $f(x)=x/\log(1+x)$ for $x>1$

Tags: special-functions

Is there an expression of $f^{-1}$ in terms of product-log or other special functions which holds for $x>1$?

WolframAlpha finds the solution:
$$g(y)=-y\,W\big(-\mathrm e^{-1/y}/y\big)-1,$$
which however only holds for $-1<x<1$, $0<y<1$.

**Edit:** Corrected $g(y)$ as per @jjagmath's comment.

Comment: The Lambert-W function is multivalued. Try using the other branch, $W_{-1}$ instead.

Comment: @user1337 I tried, without success.

Comment: The formula you typed for $g$ is not the answer from Wolfram, you missed a minus one term and a sing in the $W$ argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As user1337 said in his comment, you just need to consider the other branch of the Lambert function:

[image]